# Object checking issue in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In this code I'm checking if every key in the *obj* is squared value of *arr*. also checking if values of *obj* is equal to corresponding value quantity of *arr*. so I'm iterating *arr* and by using ***in operator*** checking if ***key ** 2*** exists in *obj*, if not doing console.log("false") if yes making subtraction of obj's property and doing console.log("true")

```js
let obj = {
  1: 1,
  4: 1,
  9: 1,
  25: 2,
};

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 2, 5];

for (let key of arr) {
  if (!(key ** 2 in obj)) {
    console.log("false");
  } else {
    obj[key ** 2] -= 1;
    console.log(obj);
    console.log("true");
  }
}
```

[image]

Here I changed ***in operator*** with ***(obj[key ** 2])***, so my question is not how to solve task properly, my question is that why in case of **in operator** and ***"(obj[key ** 2])"*** they act the way they do? in the **in operator** case subtraction of -1 continues, but in the second case, the moment when *obj*'s key is 4 and property 0 it stops subtraction, which means that **!(obj[2 ** 2])** is true therefore logs "false".

so again why in the both case they act the way they do? is there some rule or something like that? I think first case seems more logically, Thanks in advance

```js
let obj = {
  1: 1,
  4: 1,
  9: 1,
  25: 2,
};

let arr = [1, 2, 3, 2, 5];

for (let key of arr) {
  if (!(obj[key ** 2])) {
    console.log("false");
  } else {
    obj[key ** 2] -= 1;
    console.log(obj);
    console.log("true");
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Zero is falsy. `2 ** 2 = 4` and when `obj[4] = 0`, then `if (!0)` will go in the first branch and print `"false"`.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks, it is clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The `in` operator returns true if the specified property is in the specified object or its prototype chain.**
whereas, `obj[key]` returns the value of that key. so when `obj[4]` becomes `0` first block of `if` conditional executes. As `if(!0) == true`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in

in your 1st code, you are checking the keys with `!(keys ** 2 in obj)`. whenever the key is matched it returns `true`. As `if(!true) == false` the 1st block of `if` statement is skipped.